# Routing Laravel

Tags: laravel

Помогите разобраться. Запускаю комманду

```
php artisan serve
```

Стартует сервер, перехожу на страницу и мне в адрессе вместо домашней страницы подставляется вот такой роут

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login
```

В файле web.php такого роута нет.
Почему переходит по указанному адресу?

Comment: `php artisan route:list` все тебе покажет)

Answer (score 0):

Значит у тебя стоит обязательная авторизация админом, для посещения домашней страницы.

Убери обязательную авторизацию и тогда тебя должно будет кидать сразу на главную страницу.

Если не помогло,скопируй сюда все что находится в файле routes/web.php